# Why is my queue sorting input strings differently than a first in-first out basis?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to utilize a queue but the queue is reorganizing itself and I have no idea why

Everyone else who uses queues seems to have theirs working fine, and no one seems to be encountering this problem

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    PriorityQueue<String> cue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    cue.offer("this");
    cue.offer("that");
    cue.offer("then");
    System.out.printf("%s \n", cue);
    System.out.printf("%s \n", cue.peek());
    cue.poll();
    System.out.printf("%s \n", cue);
}
```

I expect it to print:

```
[this, that, then]
this
[that, then]
```

But instead it prints:

```
[that, this, then]
that
[then, this]
```

I just have no idea why

Comment: Are you sure the output is not `[that, then, this] that [then, this]`?

Comment: @daniu Output seems to be like OP describes it: https://ideone.com/gB9bcH The reason for this is that [the iterator is not ordered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--).

Comment: @daniu It would be `[this, that, then]`. After `that` is inserted, `this` becomes the left child of `that`. When `then` is inserted, it becomes the right child of `that`. Thus the order, `[that, this, then]`.

Answer (score 5):

From the java doc of `PriorityQueue`:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are **ordered according to their natural ordering**

So this is *by-design*.

You can use a `java.util.LinkedList` (which implements the `Queue` interface and will act like a first in first out queue), and will give you the expected ordering

Answer (score 2):

`PriorityQueue` does not override `toString()` from `AbstractCollection`.

From the Javadoc of [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--):

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator

[`PriorityQueue.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--) says:

> The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

So there is no guarantee that it would print the lowest element first either.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `new PriorityQueue<String>()`'s [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue()) states that it

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.

However, this should result in the output

> [that, then, this] that [then, this]

I assume the output you posted was manually typed, with a mistake - "then" should be before "this".

EDIT:
It seems like the output and the actual order in the queue are not the same.
That's misleading but explains it.

Comment: Funnily though, I too get the output the OP was stating. After some testing it seems that if `"this"` is added to the queue as the second element it is also printed in the second position, but later on will be in the correct (third)

Comment: Same here. Seems PriorityQueue simply prioritizes 1 element, and does not bother ordering the rest of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You're using a PriorityQueue, but expecting it to work like a regular Queue. A regular queue works FIFO (the way you are expecting - you put `this` in first, and `this` will be the first element). A PriorityQueue will assign a priority to it's elements and order them accordingly. By default it uses the standard compare() method of its elements, which in the case of `String`s will sort them alphabetically. After that, see the explanation below for why the contents *aren't* sorted alphabetically.

As far as I can tell (but I can't find any documentation explicitly confirming this), PriorityQueue only makes sure the first element is the 'lowest' according to natural ordering. When `.poll()`ing the queue or offering a new element that turns out to be the 'lowest', the whole contents are re-ordered to put the new 'lowest' in front. If the element in front remains the 'lowest' when changing the contents of the queue, the new element is just enqueued at the back - even if it is lower than other elements already in the queue.